# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to learn Kotlin and Retrofit. This is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.models.Post
import com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.services.JsonPlaceHolderApi
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        var jsonPlaceholderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi::class.java)
        var call: Call<List<Post>> = jsonPlaceholderApi.getPosts()
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Post>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Post>>, t: Throwable) {
                textView_result.text = t.message;
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Post>>, response: Response<List<Post>>) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textView_result.text = "Code: ${response.code()}"
                    return;
                }
                val posts: List<Post>? = response.body()
                if (posts != null) {
                    for(post in posts) {
                        var content: String = "";
                        content += "ID: ${post.id}" +
                                "\n " +
                                "USER ID: ${post.userId}" +
                                "\n " +
                                "TITLE: ${post.title}" +
                                "\n " +
                                "TEXT ${post.text}" +
                                "\n \n"
                        textView_result.append(content)
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**Post**

```
package com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.models

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class Post {
    var id: Int? = 0;
    var userId: Int? = 0;
    var title: String = "";
    @SerializedName("body")
    var text: String = "";
}
```

**JsonPlaceHolder**

```
package com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.services
import com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.models.Post
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("posts")
    fun getPosts(): Call<List<Post>>
}
```

I don't know what's wrong; it's giving me this error:

> 2020-03-16 12:27:46.696 4830-4830/com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner, PID: 4830
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner/com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.MainActivity> cannot be
> instantiated
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.kotlin.retrofitbeginner.MainActivity> cannot be
> instantiated
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
> at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

How can I debug this?